# Download RPM packages for command which is already installed

Tags: centos, yum, rpm

I have a CentOS machine in which I already installed openssl-devel using

```
$ yum install openssl-devel
```

It downloaded and installed all the dependency packages.
Now I need all those RPM packages. Is it possible to download only the RPM packages? When I do this:

```
 $ yum install  openssl-devel -y --downloadonly
```

It says

```
Package 1:openssl-devel-1.0.1e-4.fc18.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

since it's already installed.

Does anyone know how to download those RPM packages on the same system?

Answer (score 16):

It is possible to download the packages of an RPM which is already installed using the `--downloadonly` switch. I am not sure why yum doesn't check this setting before checking whether the package is already installed, but I guess it could be caused by the underlying architecture of the tool.

Anyway, all you need to do is to tell yum to **reinstall** the package:

```
yum --downloadonly --downloaddir=/tmp/rpm_files/ reinstall package_name
```

Of course, yum will not know which dependencies were installed just for this package, so if you take the RPMs and try to install them on a different system, some dependencies might be missing. There are ways to explore the whole dependency graph and I'm sure this was already described elsewhere on SE.

Answer (score 7):

`yumdownloader` in `yum-utils` will download any packages you pass to it, or optionally generate the URLs the packages can be downloaded from.

Comment: its not resolving dependencies , it just download openssl-devel.x86_64.rpm

Comment: No, it doesn't resolve dependencies. But how far back would you like the tool to resolve the dependencies? `glibc`? `filesystem`?

Comment: my requirement is simple , i need to get the list of rpms , to install it on another machine , which is in offline

Comment: You say "simple", but it's actually not as simple as you think. There is no tool that will resolve dependencies given just a list of which packages are already installed.

Comment: actually it is simple , yum install  openssl-devel -y --downloadonly if i do this command on an another machine , it will resolve all dependencies , but my question is whether its possible to do the same in a machine which we installed that command already

Comment: "It's simple, but with caveats" is *not* the same as "it's simple".

Comment: ok let it be tough as per u say , my question is whether its possible or not

Comment: Yes. But it's not trivial. No tool is designed to resolve dependencies given just a list of which packages are already installed.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [repotrack](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/repotrack.1.html) command from the yum-utils package. It will download the entire dependency tree - **even if it is already installed**.

Example:

```
sudo yum install yum-utils      # Install yum-utils
sudo repotrack openssl-devel    # Download all dependencies for openssl-devel
```

Sample output:

```
[sbadra@rhel6 ~]$ sudo yum install openssl-devel
Loaded plugins: product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
Setting up Install Process
Package openssl-devel-1.0.1e-57.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

[sbadra@rhel6 ~]$ sudo repotrack openssl-devel
Downloading audit-libs-2.4.5-6.el6.x86_64.rpm
Downloading audit-libs-2.4.5-6.el6.i686.rpm
Downloading basesystem-10.0-4.el6.noarch.rpm
Downloading bash-4.1.2-48.el6.x86_64.rpm
Downloading ca-certificates-2017.2.14-65.0.1.el6_9.noarch.rpm
Downloading chkconfig-1.3.49.5-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
Downloading coreutils-8.4-46.el6.x86_64.rpm
Downloading coreutils-libs-8.4-46.el6.x86_64.rpm
.... more packages ....
Downloading openssl-1.0.1e-57.el6.i686.rpm
Downloading openssl-1.0.1e-57.el6.x86_64.rpm
Downloading openssl-devel-1.0.1e-57.el6.i686.rpm
Downloading openssl-devel-1.0.1e-57.el6.x86_64.rpm
.... more packages ....
Downloading sed-4.2.1-10.el6.x86_64.rpm
Downloading setup-2.8.14-23.el6.noarch.rpm
Downloading tzdata-2018c-1.el6.noarch.rpm
Downloading zlib-1.2.3-29.el6.x86_64.rpm
Downloading zlib-1.2.3-29.el6.i686.rpm
Downloading zlib-devel-1.2.3-29.el6.i686.rpm
Downloading zlib-devel-1.2.3-29.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: I retracted the note about the architecture bug since it is actually the expected behavior. (x86_64 is a superset of i686, which is why the command also downloads i686 packages) See [this](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/yum/issues/25) and [this](http://yum-devel.baseurl.narkive.com/h43gi3vs/why-doesn-t-reposync-work-for-me) article for more info.

Comment: very good!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

One possibility in the longer term might be to designate a machine as the one to download from the internet, then run NFS (or a webserver) on it to expose /var/cache/yum to the internal hosts.

You would then need to update your yum config, to add:

```
[main]
keepcache = 1
```

Per https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Working_with_Yum_Cache.html:

> Once you enabled caching, every yum operation may download package data from the configured repositories.

In more practical terms:

```
$ sudo yum install -y nginx
$ sudo find /var/cache/yum/ -type f -name '*.rpm'
<...snip....>
/var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/epel/packages/nginx-1.10.2-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

The  other answers will *actually* solve your immediate issue, where this will only help if you run `yum reinstall` for the packages you already have, and want RPMs for.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I do:

```sh
sudo yum install --config=./yum.conf 
  --installroot=/tmp/f541Sdex 
  --downloadonly 
  --downloaddir /tmp/DL-e25xds 
  $(cat list-of-packages)
```