# rhel 7 development tools

Tags: linux, redhat

i cannot seem to download development tools using yum

I would like to run this command

```
yumdownloader @"Development Tools" -- resolve
```

It keeps on telling me no such package for group

```
No match for argument Development Tools
```

but this works

```
yum group install "Development Tools"
```

Comment: FWIW this worlds as expected on CentOS 6 and 7 I have to hand. I guess you didn't mean to have a space between `--` and `resolve` but that's a minor thing. Please show us the exact output from your command.

Comment: I have updated the output

Comment: That's not what I asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Per https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89315/how-to-use-yumdownloader-resolve-package-name-on-yum-y-groupinstall#89317 (and a quick check of https://linux.die.net/man/1/yumdownloader), yumdownloader is (for the purposes of this discussion) equivalent to running `yum install`.

You are trying to do a `yum groupinstall`, hence your issue.

As suggested in the Unix/Linux answer, if you really want to use yumdownloader, you need to provide it the actual packages in the group, not the group name.
In the same way you would have to do that for `yum install`.

If you check [Download RPM packages for command which is already installed](https://serverfault.com/questions/508615/download-rpm-packages-for-command-which-is-already-installed/838501#838501), there may be other ways to get the packages you want, and ones that could still allow you to use `yum groupinstall`.

Comment: I've copy+paste the OPs command onto several CentOS systems and (ignoring the -- resolve) issue it just works as expected.